# Is moksha only for the current universe or for forever?

Tags: moksha, time

The creation and destruction of the universe happen an infinite number of times.

The current universe we are living in will end someday and then after the new universe will come.

If a person gets moksha in this universe then will he escape from birth and death cycle of only the current universe or for all future universes?

Comment: "The creation and destruction of the universe happen an infinite number of times."No this is not true. "If a person gets moksha in this universe then will he escape from birth and death cycle of only the current universe or for all future universes?" for all future universes.

Comment: Yes creation and destruction of this brahmanda happens the same way like waves in seashore (Thiranga thavagham) in one of the commentries of Adi shankara.. only the jivas are different.. Same sun and moon will be there even Avatara of Vishnu wont change only Jivas will be different.. Moksha is for some jivas not all the jiva during mahapralaya after brahmas 100 years everything is in suspended state without its own awareness but the jivas in moksha would be experiencing bliss even than.. continual bliss is moksha..

Comment: Did u check related question available on site on is Moksha permanent?